# A representation-neutral derivation of $g = 2$ from the Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-spin, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

This question is largely based on Thomson's Modern Particle Physics. In the appendix of this book, Thomson uses the Dirac-Pauli representation of the Dirac equation to derive the effect of an external magnetic field on a nonrelativistic spin-half particle. The derivation makes sense, though it is very mechanical and not physically intuitive.

However, I was intrigued by a remark made earlier in the book, in Chapter 4 p.84:

> The physical predictions obtained from the Dirac equation will not depend on the specific representation used; the physics of the Dirac equation is defined by the algebra satisfied by $\alpha_x$, $\alpha_y$, $\alpha_z$ and $\beta$, not by the specific representation.

I further noticed that the definition of the spin operator given on p.87, that is,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{S} = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} \sigma & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma \end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
depends on the Dirac-Pauli representation. It seems, therefore, that the $g = 2$ result is derived in a way that obfuscates the real physics (like learning quantum mechanics exclusively within the wave mechanics formalism, without Dirac notation). This leads me to wonder: what do these derivations look like in a representation-neutral system? All of the resources I've looked at either take the same approach, or are far too technical for me to understand. Is it possible to derive the $g = 2$ result with just the Dirac equation and the defining features of its matrices?

Comment: Have you heard of the [spacetime algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_algebra)?  I feel like that could help.  See especially [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_algebra#Spacetime_algebra_description_of_relativistic_physics)